# How to populate data for MySQL and Oracle?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have to create SQL script with test data.

I would like to find a tool/mechanism to:

- specify dataset only once
- have it load data to MySQL and Oracle
- it can create native SQL or just perform inserts, I don't care

Can you guys recommend good tool for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get, I would recommand you to write the test datas in an XML/CSV file and create ETL Batch to load your database.

Take a look at [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/), free and easy to use.

Hope I could help,

Answer (score 0):

you might also look at Oracle's SQL Developer product - free and can connect to both DBs and load and export data and do SQL. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html
*There is also a free data modeler for modeling (and reverse engineering ) databases.